# How do I hide files like .DS_Store in only one folder on Mac OS X Snow Leopard to optimize Google Drive?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

I have all my folders visible right now in Snow Leopard. I just put an alias to Google Drive app on my desktop and immediately copied some files over that synced correctly. Now, I notice that '.icon' and '.DS_Store' files are in the Drive folder with the 'syncing' icon next to them. I tried to sync some more files (.mp4) and it has been about two hours and they are not syncing along with the hidden files still showing 'syncing'. The only option I have found is maybe to create an automator script that runs the terminal command to hide/unhide files and add it into context menu and use it every time I need it. That seems REALLY inefficient and annoying. There has to be a way to just unhide stuff in this one folder...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you delete the files from a shell? You can show all files with `ls -la ~/Google\ Drive` and delete the `Icon\r` file with `rm ~/Google\ Drive/Icon*`. `find ~/Google\ Drive -name .DS_Store -delete` deletes all .DS_Store files. I'm not sure if that would fix the syncing issue though.

Comment: Yeah, I can delete the '.icon' file from GUI, as well as '.DS_Store'. Removing '.icon' seems okay, but '.DS_Store' just reappears. I read its wiki page and that it is file metadata and will auto create, but not much more is said. I am not sure what you refer to with 'Icon\r' mine is just plain '.icon'. Why is the 'r' escaped there?